# In Octave/Matlab, how do I turn [1,2,4,8] into [1 1 0 1 0 0 0 1]?

Tags: matlab, octave

Or more generally, a list of integers from 1 to n into an n-dimensional vector of zeros and ones?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
A = [ 1, 2, 4, 8];
B = false( 1,A(end) );
B(A) = true;
```

returns:

```
B =

     1     1     0     1     0     0     0     1
```

and optional: `B = double(B)` if you need it as doubles.

or:

```
B = zeros( 1,A(end) );
B(A) = 1;
```

however.

Comment: why are you initializing `B` with `numel (A)`? In the example given, you would initialize a 1x4 vector which is not what was asked. Simply `B(A) = true` or `B(A) = 1` is enough.

Comment: @carandraug: `numel(A)` is nonsense, thats right. But I'd keep the initialization, to make sure all other values are `0`/`false`

Comment: all other values are false or zero by default, you don't have to worry about it. If you really want to initialize `B`, which I still think you don't have to (the assigning values to other indices **is** the initialization), use `max (A(:))`. Initializing to the wrong place will actually be worse since the assignment will force a resize.

Comment: @carandraug I disagree. If you e.g. have a variable `B = 01010101` in your workspace and assign `B(A)=true` it won't be the desired result. If you clear all before, of course you need it. But during the development process I'd keep this line.